# How to extend or modify resolved Dynamic Link at Presentation side?

Tags: content-delivery, dynamic-linking

Our business requirement is to remove `/index.aspx` from resolved Component link for the SEO purpose. Can anyone suggest me what would be the best way to achieve this with minimal effort as it's only for one website. I went through some articles but most of them are pertaining to redefine the TCDL tags, is this the only way?

```
<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:100-xxxxx-64" ComponentURI="tcm:100-xxxxx" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" LinkText="XYZ" LinkAttributes="" TextOnFail="true"/>
```

I have this tag in a published Page.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Will Price in his blog post here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/cleaning-and-extending-dynamic-linking

If you are using TCDL tags and want to change their behavior, the best solution then, is indeed to extend the linking functionality at the TCDL level, by creating our own TCDL tag.

It's very easy, you just need to create a `.jar` file with our own tag class (and put it in the `/lib` folder of your CD webservice), and configure it in the `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` file.

You can also consider to extend the logic in the .NET linking web control itself, for that Will has written another article: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/extending-linking-for-net

Comment: .NET linking web control option is easiest and quick solution for my use case. Thanks for this info !!